# Have you ever successfully negotiated rent in London? If yes, how?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental

I am new to London and just moved here from NYC. I am on the hunt for a 1-bed apartment and I noticed that when I ask landlords/agents if the rent is negotiable, they stop responding. I had a couple of people do that. It is common to attempt to negotiate rent in NY and in other metropolitan cities where I've lived, doesn't mean you will get it but you surely can ask and it sometimes works too.

There is an apartment I like in Surrey Quays, so my questions are: Have any of you successfully negotiated rent in London before? And if yes, what would be your tips and ways on how to go about it? Do you ask before or after you see the apartment? Over text or in person, etc.?

Thanks for all your feedback in advance :)

Comment: I've negotiated a rent _increase_, but that's a different situation, as the landlord has an interest to keep the same tenant, in particular if they know it to be a good one.

Comment: You mean a rent decrease, I assume? And yes, having been a tenant with the landlord already is an advantage. But how did you go about anyway?

Comment: I negotiated a reduction of the rent increase :) The landlady proposed to increase the rent by £30/month and I proposed to instead increase the rent by £10/month.  This happened in an exchange of e-mails via the letting agent.  "The landlady proposes to increase the rent by £30/month" "We propose to increase the rent by £10/month instead" "The landlady agrees".

Comment: London's (and, in fact, [UK](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-66246223)) property rental market has been red-hot in the past couple of years. Each listing would likely have at least a couple offers above the asking price, which explains why landlords/agents ghost you upon asking whether the rent amount is negotiable. No comments on whether it is in their best interest to do so in the long run.